# Stuck in the Reduce Join Code

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, mapper, reducers

I have two datasets. both are given below

1st dataset

```
1   A
2   B
3   C
4   D
5   E
```

2nd dataset

```
1   ALPHA
2   BRAVO
3   CHARLIE
4   DELTA
5   ECHO
```

**I want to join this dataset using reduce side join**
the final data is supposed to appear like this

---

```
A   ALPHA
B   BRAVO
C   CHARLIE
D   DELTA
E   ECHO
```

I wrote the following codes
**Mapper**(extracting data from 1st dataset)

```
public class indMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text,IntWritable, Text> {
    private String tokens[];
    public void map(Object key,Text value,Context context)throws IOException,InterruptedException{
        tokens=value.toString().split("\t");
        context.write(new IntWritable(Integer.parseInt(tokens[0].toString().trim())), new Text("m1"+"\t"+tokens[1].trim()));
    }
}
```

**Mapper** (extracting data from second dataset)

```
public class AlphaMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, IntWritable, Text> {
        private String tokens[];
        public void map(Object key,Text value,Context context)throws IOException,InterruptedException{
            tokens=value.toString().split("\t");
            context.write(new IntWritable(Integer.parseInt(tokens[0].toString().trim())), new Text("m2"+"\t"+tokens[1].trim()));
        }
}
```

**Reducer** (Joining the data as desired)

```
public class JoinReducer extends Reducer<IntWritable, Text, Text, Text> {
    private String output1=new String();
    private String output2=new String();
    private TreeMap<String,String> x1=new TreeMap<String,String>();
    private String tokens[];
    public void reduce(IntWritable key,Text value,Context context)throws IOException,InterruptedException{
            tokens=value.toString().split("\t");
            if(tokens[0].contains("m1"))
            {
                output1=tokens[1];
            }else if(tokens[0].contains("m2"))
            {
                output2=(tokens[1]);
            }
            x1.put(output2, output1);
        cleanup(context);

}
    public void cleanup(Context context)throws IOException,InterruptedException{

        for(Entry y:x1.entrySet())
        {
            context.write(new Text(" "), new Text(y.getKey().toString()+","+y.getValue().toString()));
        }
    }
}
```

**In the driver class following lines have been included**

```
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(j, new Path(arg0[0]),TextInputFormat.class,indMapper.class);
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(j, new Path(arg0[1]),TextInputFormat.class,AlphaMapper.class);
```

I am getting an output like the one given below, which is not at all as desired.

```
1       m1      A
1       m2      ALPHA
2       m2      BRAVO
2       m1      B
3       m1      C
3       m2      CHARLIE
4       m2      DELTA
4       m1      D
5       m1      E
5       m2      ECHO
```

I absolutely am not able to figure out why the indexes are getting printed eventhough I haven't included the index into the `context.write()`

I have even used a cleanup(), still getting the same result.
Please suggest how to get the results as desired, given above.

Heartiest thanks to the one who gets me out of this mess :)

Later on after few modifications, I am getting this output

```
m1      E
m1      D
m1      C
m1      B
m1      A
m2      ECHO
m2      DELTA
m2      CHARLIE
m2      BRAVO
m2      ALPHA
```

Comment: Think this should be your mapper output

Comment: No, not actually this is unfortunately the reducer output. The issue is, I am not able to align the values emitted from the reducer into a single line. Later on I got some output like the one that I am going to update into the questions area.

Comment: but m1 or m2 is not part of your tree map right?

Comment: right? still they are getting into the output. I am trying to solve the same by virtue of further analysis. Let's see what happens next?
You may suggest me, at your convinience, the points or the lines in the codes which may be faulty
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Yes anirudh, your reducer itself was not called because of incorrect signature as rightly pointed by ramzy. Therefore the output you are getting is just the mappers output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modified code may be as below

```
 public void reduce(IntWritable key,Iterabale<Text> values,Context context)throws IOException,InterruptedException{

               for(Text value : values) {
                tokens=values.toString().split("\t");
                if(tokens[0].contains("m1"))
                {
                    output1=tokens[1];
                }else if(tokens[0].contains("m2"))
                {
                    output2=(tokens[1]);
                }
                x1.put(output2, output1);
               }
            cleanup(context);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The reducer method should be having key and Iterable values as arguments. And each reducer will be having data in the below format

{1, {"m1 A","m2 ALPHA"}}, {1, {"m2 BA","m2 BRAVO"}}.

Please recheck the signature of reducer method. I assume once this is solved, and if your data is one to one, you can map accordingly. If it is one to many, you might have multiple m1's or m2's and for that, yo need to decide how that multi values are managed(map be keep as comma separated or in a json or xml string) and then output the final value.